# Не получается запустить веб-приложение C# используя протокол HTTPS на localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, https, localhost

Пытаюсь запустить веб-приложение из Microsoft Docs Tutorial - Get started with Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core.

IIS Express Development Certificate для localhost - установлен. **Если запускаю приложение с использованием Microsoft Internet Explorer - всё работает нормально.** А если с Microsoft Edge, Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox = нет.

Вот сообщение от Microsoft Edge:

> Подключение к этому сайту не защищено
> На сайте localhost используется неподдерживаемый протокол.
> ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

> Неподдерживаемый протокол
> Клиент и сервер не поддерживают стандартную версию протокола SSL или комплект шифров.

Поиск решения в Google, Yandex, StackOverflow ни к чему не привёл. Предлагаемые решения не помогли.

P.S.
Windows 7 SP1 64x Домашняя расширенная. Все обновления.
Visual Studio Community 2019. Все обновления.
Приложение на C# с использованием .NET 5.
В свойствах Интернет (Windows) отмечены SSL 2.0, SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 и TLS 1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена!

Нужно внести изменение в реестр Windows 7:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server

- DisabledByDefault REG_DWORD 0
- Enabled REG_DWORD 1

Comment: а можно ссылку на документацию пожалуйста, ну или хотя бы откуда взят ответ, ресурс ?